# Flutter: Filter products by categories in the app level?

Tags: database, performance, flutter, dart, categories

I am currently trying to develop an app in which products are categorically displayed in a separate screen or class with ListView.builder ().

I have to select / favor a category or sub-category so that I can see products in the list view. I see nothin in the screen if i don't select one or more categorys OR subcategorys. I can also favor different categories and in the list view I see the products that match the favorite product. If I have favored a subcategory, I should only see in the list view the products that see in this favored subcategory and not the superordinate categories.
If I prefer a higher category, all products of the subcategories should be shown in the list view.

But I'm worried about the performance. My database will run on Firebase. Is firestore more suitable for this? I also read that relational databases are more suitable for such things. However, I have never worked with it and I want the favorites not only to be saved on the smartphone. I would like the favorites to be called up when the user logs in to the app with another phone.

My question is more of a structural question. Is it better for the performance if there is a Category class in which all higher and lower categories each have a list with the products and which are then merged in the list view (if different categories are selected, of course)?

I mean, if I list all the products in a single list and filter them afterwards in the code (at the app level), it is totally unperforming, right?

Do I have to have a class category and a separate subcategory class? How would you go about it? I have total chaos in my brain

class Product:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final List<String> imagesPath;
  final String description;
  final Color categoryColor;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.imagesPath,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.categoryColor,
  });
}
```

class Category:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/Product.dart';

class Category {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  bool isFavourite;
  final List<Product> products;

  Category({@required this.title, @required this.color, this.isFavourite = false, this.products});
}

List<Category> categories = [
  Category(
    title: 'Automobile',
    color: Colors.lightBlue,
    isFavourite: false,
  ),
];
```

I no longer know which would be more correct in terms of how I should go on.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Cloud Firestore as it provides [query functionalities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) that Firebase Realtime Database does not.

You can check this similar answer I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722282/2497859) where I've demonstrated querying Firestore data and filtering displayed data based from the selected item.