# How to display the data from firebase using FutureBuilder in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
    Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getData() async {
var firestore = Firestore.instance;
QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore
    .collection("LiveGames")
    .where("Title", isEqualTo: "Solo")
    .getDocuments();
return qn.documents;
```

}

I have extracted the data using this function getData() to use it in the FutureBuilder.

```
  FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 50,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: SpinKitCircle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(91, 74, 127, 10),
                  size: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,

            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: 185,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                              color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                            ),
                            height: 150,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 6,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text("Date",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                          Text(
                                              snapshot.data[index]
                                                  .data["GameDate"],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text("Time",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                          Text(
                                              snapshot.data[index]
                                                  .data["GameTime"],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text("Map",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                          Text(
                                              snapshot.data[index]
                                                  .data["MapName"],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text("Mode",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                          Text(
                                              snapshot.data[index]
                                                  .data["GameMode"],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Divider(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text("Players Joined",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                          Text(
                                              "${snapshot.data[index].data["RemainingPlayers"]}",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text("Winning",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                          Expanded(
                                              child: FlatButton(
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                                    size: 18,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                  ),
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    showModalBottomSheet(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          Colors.orange
                                                              .shade500,
                                                      shape:
                                                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                              borderRadius:
                                                                  BorderRadius
                                                                      .only(
                                                        topLeft:
                                                            Radius.circular(
                                                                15),
                                                        topRight:
                                                            Radius.circular(
                                                                15),
                                                      )),
                                                      context: context,
                                                      builder: (context) {
                                                        return Container(
                                                          child: Column(
                                                            children: <Widget>[

                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        );
                                                      },
                                                    );
                                                  }))
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text("Remaining Players",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                          Text(
                                              "${snapshot.data[index].data["TotalSeats"]}",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Divider(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Column(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text("Per Kill",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                )),
                                            Text(
                                                "₹ ${snapshot.data[index].data["PerKill"]}",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                )),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Column(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text("Entry Fees",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                )),
                                            Text(
                                                "₹ ${snapshot.data[index].data["Entryfees"]}",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                )),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150),
                            height: 35,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 125),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print("Solo Joined");
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  "Join Contest",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    },
  ),
```

And then i have displayed some Widgets according to the data. 
[image: Firebase Data]
[image: Firebase Data]

But in database i have some rank values and i want to display the data in the bottomsheet if the rank from 2 to 10 and 11 to 20 and 21 to 40 are zeros i do not want to display in the bottom sheet only rank1 player i want it to display but if Rank1 player and all the players from rank 1 to 40 some values are there then i have to display the all the data in the bottomSheet

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I don't see any issues on using `FutureBuilder` in Flutter. The issue here seems to lean more on how you can manage your Firestore data to be displayed.

If you'd like to filter out `Players` to be displayed base from their `Rank`. What you can do here is create a `Collections` for `Players` where you can sort them by `Rank`.

Say you'd only like to display Players with Rank 1 in your List.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('players')
    .where('rank', isEqualTo: 1)
    .snapshots()
```

For `Rank` with ranges, say Ranks 2-10, [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) can be utilized. For querying in Flutter, you can check the [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) for its equivalence.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('players')
    .where('rank', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 2)
    .where('rank', isLessThanOrEqualTo: 10)
    .snapshots()
```

Here's a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722282) that I posted previously that filters and displays all carModels base from the selected carMake. It uses `StreamBuilder` though. I'm curious on your choice for using `FutureBuilder` instead of `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

##### Try the following example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore
                .instance
                .collection('users') //  Your collection name here
                .get(), 
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['avatar']), //  Your valid data here
            );
          }).toList());
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```

Also refer: [How to use `StreamBuilder` and `FutureBuilder` for single and multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75148843/13431819)